# how to trap a URL in iOS web browser in livecode 8.1x

Tags: ios, livecode

I am quite new to LiveCode trying to build a web browser app for iOS which only opens a specic domain/website.

I found building a web browser for iOS in the latest LiveCode 8.1x was so easy but could not figure out how to trap a URL clicked in a webpage and send it to the default web browser if the URL is out of the domain.

Does anyone know how?

Comment: You con do it through adding search bar. on click search you again pass the url to web view and reload it. sorry for bad english.

Comment: Thank you very much. What about a hyperlink? Do you know how to trap a URL when a hyperlink in a webpage is clicked?

Answer (score 1):

When the URL of the browser changes, I'll check the domain.

For example:

```
on browserDocumentLoadBegin pUrl
   #test if domain if https://livecode.com
   if char 1 to 20 of pURL is not "https://livecode.com" then
      alert "wrong domain"
      set the URL of me to "www.livecode.com"      
   end if
end browserDocumentLoadBegin
```